# remove all selections from Jquery chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am using Jquery [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin for Multiple Select. I have to add a Reset button to clear all the selected items but not sure where to proceed.
Already tried `.clear` `.val([])` on it but nothing helped. How do you clear all the selected items?
Plain javascript pointers would be helpful over jQuery based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on page one select with chousen it will help

```
$('.chzn-container li.search-choice').remove()
```

Comment: As of the newest release the class name is now `chosen-container` not `chzn-container`